# Firebase query not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is not working query not working even though the uuid is correct

```
post
{
   "-K_EAmNl7RdB9YTG02y3" : {
   "authorId" : "SjrT3T3HgPaYh6KNDlGiBNcDitb2",
   "body" : "Charly guys u should",
   "commentCount" : 0,
   "date" : 1483092207310,
   "likeCount" : 3,
   "likes" : {
      "SjrT3T3HgPaYh6KNDlGiBNcDitb2" : true,
      "z9nZPm09BSS5DQ522bS2ZxeXQYP2" : true
     },
   "postColor" : "607D8B",
   "postId" : "-K_EAmNl7RdB9YTG02y3"
},

}
```

Code:

```
Query query = postRef.orderByChild("authorId").equalTo(uuid);
```

Is not working query not working even though the uuid is correct

Comment: The code above just builds a `Query` object, but doesn't yet retrieve any data? What isn't working? Please share the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Have you attached the Query to a ValueEventListener or ChildEventListener?